# Jmeter is downloading a 67Mb file but only saving 10,240 KB

Tags: download, jmeter, zip

Bit of Background, I am using Jmeter to search for a download url from a rest API with an Oauth authorisation token set from the rest API. Once I have this URL I am doing a HTTP request, GET with redirect automatically, keepAlive and browser-compatible headers all checked.

Hanging of this I have then attached a "Save response to a file" with the file name prefix set to "blob" (this will be a filename set by a parameter later) and Add timestamp to the file name checked.

The url in question points to a zip file that needs OAuth header token (which is set successfully) the whole test plan succeeds.
This is great and you can see looking at the results
[image: results]

You can see that there are 67821343 bytes downloaded by the HTTP Request this is what we are expecting to see as this is the size of the file around 67Mb

This is were it starts to go wrong however as the save file only has 10,240 KB is an OCTET-Stream File and renaming this file to a zip just does not work as it is not a complete zip file.

This is my issue the Save file is not saving all the information and only save 10,240KB, every single time.

- What am i doing wrong?
- Is there a better way to get this zip file?

Please help it is driving me mad.
As once I have downloaded it I then need to assess the contents of the zip file to prove that the download URL that we are being directed to contains the correct ZIP.
here's the RUB if i do it manually through a browser i get the file downloaded successfully and it is exactly the same size (67821343 Bytes) but it just doesn't save in Jmeter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following property to *user.properties* file:

```
httpsampler.max_bytes_to_store_per_request=73400320
```

This will allow JMeter to save files up to 70MB

You can also set this property to `0` - in this case JMeter will not truncate data (make sure you amend [JVM heap](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13814/jvm_tuning.htm#PERFM150) so responses could fit in memory)

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: thank you. I ended up setting it to httpsampler.max_bytes_to_store_per_request=1174405120 (roughly 1.2G ) this limitation might cause issues later when trying to download a 40Gb File but i guess I will have to cope with that later. (satellite images I tried setting it higher but it seems to not like it). I also set the heap size to 20G (yes its huge my machine can cope with it). Thank you once again